# error LNK2005: _main already defined in hold.obj

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Hi  Please i have browsed all same error that i got but I didnt get solving for my problem, so `I am using MS VC++ 2010` and i have two files `a.c and b.c,` each one works no error alone and each one has a simple code and clear. But when i use them to gather shows this error `**error LNK2005: _main already defined in  a.c **` this same error shows on Code block IED. I think that refer to using main function twice. Now how can i use one main function for both file

Code file a.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
    int a =9;
    if(a==7)
    {
        puts("This is number seven ");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("This isn't number seven ");
    }

    getch();
}
```

Code file b.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
    int x=10;

    printf("%d", x);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: can you please post your codes for both a.c and b.c? It doesn't really make any sense. Also, if using 2 main funcs is the problem, create `exec_main.c` file and put your main function in there.

Comment: `Now how can i use one main function for both file` Define a single `main` function.

Comment: @user657267    correct! Also, you know that everything runs from one main thread, so you cannot have two anyway

Comment: The linker is telling you that you have `main` defined twice because you have `main`  defined twice.

Comment: But please how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @Basil Delete the main() function from one of your files, so you're left with just the one main() function you want. Or perhaps you need to create separate projects for your 2 programs, if you actually have 2 separate programs.

Comment: How can i define a single main function for both files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible to have two main functions, a program starts running in only 1 main function. You could rename the main functions, and create one main function that calls them both.

```
Code file a.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void a_main()
{
    int a =9;
    if(a==7)
    {
        puts("This is number seven ");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("This isn't number seven ");
    }


    getch();
}
```

Code file b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
   a_main();
   b_main();
}

void b_main()
{
    int x=10;

    printf("%d", x);
    getch();
}
```

Note, it is good practice to carfully name functions so that the names describe what they do. Eg, in this example you might call a_main PrintIs7OrNot and b_main Print10.

Comment: @Basil - How many? Do you need all of these main functions in one program, or could they each be in their own program? You could just carry on: c_main, d_main, e_main, etc.

Comment: Really thanks Scott and please i like to ask you anther think now the main active file is a.c is running it code so how can i make b.c the active to run it code?

Comment: @Basil - Sorry, I don't understand your question. If you use the example I gave in the answer, a_main() should run and after that b_main() should run. You can change the code in main() to put these two functions in the other order if you want.

Comment: @ScottLangham I want to ask a question on the same topic that what to do if I want to run both the programs individually? Do I have to make another new project for a new program or can I do it in the same project by adding a new file?

Comment: @AsheeshSahu It depends which tools you are using to write your program. C++ has no concept called Project, but the tools you use to write you program in may organize files into Projects.  I use Visual Studio to write C++, in Visual Studio you need a new project for every program.