# I want to run multi-files in c project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, embedded

I have a C project which contains two files:

- learn11.c
- test.c

Both have main function. When I run the windows debugger it can't find the specified file to debug with error (LNK2005  main already defined in learn11.obj).

So how can I choose the file I want to debug?

I tried many times but the only way is to cancel one of the mains function and I don't want to do that.

Comment: If you are getting failures from the linker, as it says you already have one `main()` function. There can only be one `main()` function in a set of linked modules. You can 'comment out' one of them, or perhaps use conditional compilation to compile one or the other.

Comment: You need to separate the projects. One project (that is, one resulting executable) can only have exactly one `main()`. (There are duplicates here on SO, for sure, but I don't have the time to look for them...)

Comment: That sounds more like a Visual Studio 2022 error than a VS Code error. Would be worth it to adjust the tags to match what you're actually using if it is not VS Code.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583763/error-lnk2005-main-already-defined-in-hold-obj. Also confirm you're talking about _Visual Studio Code_ rather than _Visual Studio_, these are two totally different products even if their names are similar. [Edit] and correct if necessary.

Comment: It is an X-Y problem.  Your problem is your code won't link, but you are asking how to run the code in the debugger.  There is no code to run until it links.  The solution is not clear without sight of the code.  Why for example do these two files need to be in the same executable?  Do they share any code?

Comment: Why does this have the [embedded] tag?

Answer (score 0):

What behavior are you expecting? You cannot have multiple `main()` functions in the project. The `main()` function is how it knows where to enter the project and start executing it. It is like you are presenting a person with two doors and instructing them to go through both of them simultaneously! You have to pick one or the other. If you want to execute both files, one after the other (that's the only choice*), rename your current `main()` functions to something else and create a new `main()`, perhaps in a new file, that calls each of the newly-renamed functions in the proper order. For example if your `learn11.c` says this:

```c
int main(void) {
    printf("learn11\n");
}
```

and your `test.c` says this:

```c
int main(void) {
    printf("test\n");
}
```

then rename the first function `learn11()` and the second `test()`, and add a `main()` to invoke both:

`learn11.c`:

```c
int learn11(void) {
    printf("learn11\n");
}
```

`test.c`:

```c
int test(void) {
    printf("test\n");
}
```

new file main.c:

```
int learn11(void);
int test(void);

int main(void) {
    learn11();
    test();
}
```

(The two lines at the top are declarations so that the file is aware of these functions; normally you'd put these in an include file, but I am simplifying things.)

*Pedant note: I am ignoring parallel processing for this simple case!